# how to create REAL global object in v8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scope, window, v8

I used v8 engine to create a program , it can run JS codes like :

```
alert('test');  // alert function is created in C++ and set global to v8 context. so it can be run.

window.name = 'aa'; // window object is exported from C++ to v8 enviroment.
```

But, if I set property to window object like :

```
window.name ='aa';
```

then, I visit it :

```
alert(name); // --------> this caused error that name is undefined...
```

In Chrome , we can set property , anything string for the window property name . it runs fine.

So how can I implement that ? it seems that the window is real global in JS context.

My code :

```
Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);


Handle<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> log_ft = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, log_Callback);
log_ft->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
global->Set(isolate, "alert", log_ft);


Handle<Context> context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);
Context::Scope context_scope(context);


// set global objects and functions

Local<Object> obj( Object::New(isolate));
context->Global()->Set( String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "window"), obj );



runJSCode(context, (char*)"window.name =33; alert(name);");

std::cout << "********* v8 executed finished !! ********** \n";
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to call "alert" with "window.name" instead of just "name".

```
runJSCode(context, (char*)"window.name =33; alert(window.name);");
```

"window.name" means a property "name" of object "window", but just "name" means property name of objet "this" (that is in this case the object you get by calling "context->Global()" in C++ code). You set "window" as a property of the global object not as global object.

Comment: I think, that is what the OP asked, how to make `name` global without referring to `window.name`.

Answer (score -3):

```
//Local<Object> obj( Object::New(isolate));
//context->Global()->Set( String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "window"), obj );

runJSCode(context, (char*)"window=this; window.name =33; alert(name);");
```

====
so easy -_-!

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.